# power cable: more strands, or bigger strands?

Tags: wire

I have two types of 4awg wire to chose from to wire an inverter in my jeep.  One of them has about a dozen 20awg wires inside of it, and the other has about 100 super little wires inside of it.  Both are copper.  Which would be the better one to use?

Edit: The strands inside of the large wire are not individually insulated, they are all wrapped in one common insulator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the inside wires themselves are not individually insulated it will make no difference.

If they each have their own insulation, it would be called [litz wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire), and then the only difference will occur at high frequencies due to the [skin effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) and the [proximity effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_effect_%28electromagnetism%29). I don't think your inverter application will achieve frequencies that make any difference here. If you were using it for such a thing, the 20awg individually insulated wires would be fine until ~8KHz and the 100 individually insulated super little ones would probably be fine into the 1MHz range, it depends on its diameter.

So basically, whichever one you like. Flip a coin.

Comment: I'd additionally suggest to use whichever is the more flexible. It will be easier to work with and resist vibration more.

Comment: The one with finer strands will be much more flexible and less susceptible to fatigue in a high-vibration environment such as a vehicle.

Comment: Tanks a lot.  The inverter is powered from my car battery, so ideally there would be no frequency at all.  Even if there is, it is still DC current so it shouldn't matter.